# Write jquery scripts dynamic

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to write scripts in jQuery for checkbox's event's dynamically, this is my html code:

```html
<fieldset>
  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="radio0" id="radio0">
                    <img id="img0" src="web_bg.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
                </label>
  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio1">
                    <img id="img1" src="web_bg.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
                </label>
  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="radio2" id="radio2">
                    <img id="img2" src="web_bg.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
                </label>
  <label id="label">3</label>
</fieldset>
```

and this is my jQuery script that works:

```js
  $('#radio0').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#img0').css("opacity", "0.5");
    } else {
      $('#img0').css("opacity", "1");
    }
  });
$('#radio1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#img1').css("opacity", "0.5");
  } else {
    $('#img1').css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
$('#radio2').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#img2').css("opacity", "0.5");
  } else {
    $('#img2').css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```

but i want to put this code in a buckle like this (but this doesn't works):

```js
var text = $('#label').text();
var max = parseInt(text);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('#radio' + i + '').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#img' + i + '').css("opacity", "0.5");
    } else {
      $('#img' + i + '').css("opacity", "1");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use classes:

```js
$('.radio').click(function() {               // give your radios a class of radio
  var $thisRadio = $(this),                  // get current radio
    $thisImage = $thisRadio.next('.image');  // get corresponding image to the radio (I have given images a class of image)

  if ($thisRadio.is(':checked')) {
    $thisImage.css("opacity", "0.5");
  } else {
    $thisImage.css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="radio0" id="radio0" class="radio">
      <img id="img0" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" width="200" height="200" class="image"/>
  </label>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio1" class="radio">
      <img id="img1" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" width="200" height="200" class="image"/>
  </label>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="radio2" id="radio2" class="radio">
      <img id="img2" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" width="200" height="200" class="image"/>
  </label>
  <label id="label">3</label>
</fieldset>
```

Please also note - radio buttons in the same group should have the same name, otherwise you may as well use a checkbox